# verb-て+いたい vs verb-たい

Tags: grammar

I can't seem to wrap my head around the form verb-て+いたい

Is it a conjugation of verb-て+いる, or is it its own form?

And how is it different from verb-たい ?  It seems to be translated the same.

Some examples:

```
食べていたい vs 食べたい 
愛を信じていたい vs 愛を信じたい 
壊さないでいたい vs 壊したくない 
はなれないでいたい vs はなれたくない 
勉強していたい vs 勉強したい
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32856

Answer (score 4, accepted):

～ていたい is the combination of ～ている and ～たい ("want to ～"). ～ている describes [the continuation of an action ("is doing") and the continuation of a state ("has done")](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010).

So 見たい is "want to watch", whereas 見ていたい is "want to be watching." Typically ～ていたい is used when you have already started something and want to continue what you are doing.

> - テレビを見たい。
>     I want to watch TV.
> - もっとテレビを見ていたい。
>     I want to keep watching TV. / I want to watch TV more.

The difference between 壊さないでいたい and 壊したくない is somewhat obscure, but the former basically says you want to *keep* the current "not-broken" status.

Sometimes ～ていたい can also describe the continuation of state until some time point in the future. Using a typical instant state-change verb 結婚する ("to get married"):

> - 5年後に結婚していたい。
>     I want to be married within five years. (literally "I want to have gotten married in five years" i.e., I want to be in the 'married' state in five years)
> - 5年後に結婚したい。
>     I want to marry after 5 years from now. (i.e., I don't want to marry for the time being)